# Why this show undefined in javaScript

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why this is saying that the len is undefined :

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).value is not a function

**CODE :**

```html
<body>
  <html>
    <body>
      <p id="demo">Click the button to change the text in this paragraph.</p>

      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
      <p id="para"></p>

      <script>
        var len ;
        function myFunction() {
          len = document.getElementById("demo").value() ;

          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";

          document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = len ;

        }
      </script>

    </body>
  </html>
```

Please help.

Comment: what's your demo element?

Comment: because you have no element named `demo`, so your getElemetnById() call fails, which means `value()` fails, blah blah blah.

Comment: There is no element with id `demo`... It doesn't magically appear

Comment: <p> element as no value() . try `len = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;`

Comment: Why do you have 2 `body` tags? Doesn't change your issue, but I'm just curious.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Nobody changed the code, only the formatting.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki why do you roll back a question to where required information was missing? Please take a look at the edit history first...

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki :D

Answer (score 1):

The `demo` element is a paragraph `p` and patagraphs don't have `value` attribute, use `textContent` instead to get/set the text :

```
len = document.getElementById("demo").textContent; //get ndoe Text
document.getElementById("para").textContent = len; //set ndoe Text
```

**NOTE 1 :** `.value()` is not a javascript function you may mean `.value`.

**NOTE 2 :** `innerHTML` return the node `html content` you don't have to use it if you want just the text.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Use textContent, [innerText is non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText).

Comment: Thanks for your intervention @Pavlo .. check my update using `textContent` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `innerHTML` instead of `value()` to get the value of the demo element.A paragraph tag doesn't have a value.

> Also .value() is not a javascript function. You use `.value`
>   attribute.

```html
<p id="demo">Click the button to change the text in this paragraph.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="para"></p>

<script>
var len ;
function myFunction() {
     len = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ;

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";

    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = len ;

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `<p>` has no `value`, to get the text use

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

`len = document.getElementById("`**demo**`").value() ;`

There's nothing in your HTML with an `id` of "demo".